# Suppress page numbers when using \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have a table of contents in my memoir book. I want there to be one line for each chapter, in addition to headings for each set of similar chapters.

However, I do not want any page numbers to be displayed across from the "headings" (for which I am using the command `\addcontentsline`).

In the following MWE, for example, I do not want a page number for "Topic 1" or "Topic 2".

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 1}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

This is the first chapter.

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
This is the second chapter.

\chapter{Chapter 3}
This is the third chapter.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: I guess that `\part` is a proper way to do this. It typesets "Part" page and adds a ToC line. It might be a bit strange to have something in ToC that is not in the main document. The presence of parts does not affect chapter numbering at all.

Comment: @tohecz Thanks!  Would you mind please explaining what the exact command would be, if I want to use `\part` to accomplish this in my MWE?

Comment: See daleif's answer below...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using `\addcontentsline`, you can use

```
\cftaddtitleline{<ext>}{<kind>}{<text>}{<page>}
```

to  write a `\contentsline` entry of type `<kind>` into the file with extension `<ext>`; this line will typeset `<text>` and will use `<page>` as the page number. A little example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{Topic 1}{}
\chapter{Chapter One}

\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{Topic 2}{}
\chapter{Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What would be a similar strategy with the `book` class?

Comment: Note: If you do not use the `memoir` class, you need to load the package `tocloft` for this solution to work; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179108/undefined-control-sequence-on-cftaddtitleline

Comment: This mwe doesn't compile for me. I get `Undefined control sequence` in `main.toc` on line `\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}Chapter One}{3}{}%`

Answer (score 1):

If topics are part-like, then just use `\part` (restyle it if needed) and ask the TOC not to print part page numbers

Comment: Would you mind please explaining what the exact command would be, if I want to use `\part` to accomplish this in my MWE?

Comment: In your example now just add: `\cftpagenumbersoff{part}`. Using `\part` you will get a part page. If you want to remove the autogenerated part number in the toc: `\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{}`

Comment: @daleif It is better to edit your answer to add some more details and explanations, instead of putting them into comments ;)