# Undefined control sequence on \cftaddtitleline

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

The following code produces `! Undefined control sequence.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Topic 1}{}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?
I need `\cftaddtitleline` to add text in TOC for pages which are written in Word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to load the `tocloft` package providing the `\cftaddtitleline` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Topic 1}{}
\end{document}
```

or switch to the `memoir` document class which also provides the command:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Topic 1}{}
\end{document}
```