# frontis instead of page number in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am using the code

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.jpg}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Image caption}
```

to add a frontispiece image to my document along with an entry in the List of Figures. Is there a way to replace the page number for this entry in the List of Figures with the word "frontis"?

Comment: It much depends on how you make the frontispiece. Are you using `titlepage` or what?

Comment: @egreg I made the frontispiece manually by simply putting an `includegraphics` command on an empty page in the `article` class. So I guess my question might boil down to whether I can replace the page number with arbitrary text when adding a manual entry to the lof.

Comment: Maybe `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{caption}{frontis}}` would work (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203158/how-to-add-custom-lines-with-specified-page-number-to-the-table-of-contents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package which enables control of many aspects of the ToC and friends.

```
% frontispieceprob.tex  SE 576148

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
THE FRONTISPIECE
\vspace{4\baselineskip}

% The frontispiece picture and caption
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.jpg}
\begin{center}
Image caption
\end{center}
% add it to the LoF
\cftlocalchange{lof}{3em}{2.55em} % need more space for page designation
\cftaddtitleline{lof}{figure}{Image caption}{frontis} % the LoF entry
\cftlocalchange{lof}{1.55em}{2.55em} % revert to normal page number space

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{A Chapter}
\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{An illustration}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you don't increase the allowable space for page numbers then the dotted line continues into "frontis".

I've just done a crude frontispiece page; I'm sure yours is much better.

[image]