# How can I add an annex without page number to table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, page-numbering, appendices, appendix

I am trying to add an Annex to my thesis. I've written it in document class, **report**.

I don't want it show the page number of Annex in the table of contents.

So far I've tried using `\pagestyle{empty}`.

But it didn't work.

```
%===========
%Bibliography
%===========
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\large References}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\bibliography{lsra,biblo,ls1,lsra2}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\pagebreak
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\large Annex}

\newlength{\originalVOffset}
\newlength{\originalHOffset}
\setlength{\originalVOffset}{\voffset}   
\setlength{\originalHOffset}{\hoffset}

\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap3.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap4.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap5.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap6.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap7.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap8.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap9.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{ap10.pdf}
\setlength{\voffset}{\originalVOffset}
\setlength{\hoffset}{\originalHOffset}

\pagebreak
```

[image: The table on contents that I got.]

I do not want that page no 30 on the right of Annex.

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Edit:: Here's my preamble>> https://pastebin.com/fYtRFxeN

Here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{foo}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \pagebreak
    
    \chapter*{bar}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bar}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \pagebreak
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annex}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \pagebreak
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make a self-contained question (see [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)). External links can break, and that would make your question useless for this site in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @Miyase Thanks. I added the MWE.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this problem on the `tocloft`'s documentation itself.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{foo}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \pagebreak
    
    \chapter*{bar}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bar}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    \clearpage

    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annex}
    \chapter*{Annex}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \pagebreak
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a suboptimal solution because for anything after your annex, page numbers will not appear. A better approach is using `\cftaddtitleline{<ext>}{<kind>}{<text>}{<page>}`, which I found in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50040/31283).

Comment: Thank you celdor!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50040/31283) provides a good solution, that is one can use the macro `\cftaddtitleline{<ext>}{<kind>}{<text>}{<page>}` from [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), e.g.

```latex
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{Annex}{}
\chapter*{Annex}
```

The MWE

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\title{The title}
\author{First Second}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{Annex}{}
\chapter*{Annex}
\kant[5]

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\kant[1]

\chapter{Second}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]